# Rotate on mouseDrag

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Hello i want to rotate grid on `mouseDragged` or `mousePressed`. My code is working but when i stop mouse press the rotation is going to the start point and not redraw the grid . Kindly guide me How i can redraw grid after i finish dragging or mouse press to its end point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused, because the variable `angle` declared local and initialized by 0 in each frame.

Move the variable declaration to global scope. e.g.:

```js
let angle = 0;

function draw() {

    // [...]

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        angle =  atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

---

Extension according to the comment.

> how can i start dragging again from its end position

Use [`mouseReleased()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseReleased) event callback to manage the angle.
Add a permanent angle and a current angle:

```js
let permanent_angle = 0;

function  mouseReleased() {
    let angle =  atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
    permanent_angle += angle;
}

function draw() {

    // [...]

    let current_angle = 0;
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        current_angle =  atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
    }

     translate(width / 2, height / 2);
     rotate(permanent_angle + current_angle);
     translate( -width / 2 + 20, -height / 2 +20 );

     // [...]
}
```